# Fetching body text from a URL

Tags: android

I want to read a URL and get the body content to a string. See below code. It is returning an error as 'fail to connect '10.10.10.23'. But I can see that url in browser without any problem. Could anyone help?

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String title ="";
        //Document doc;
        try {


            URL url = new URL("http://10.10.10.23/Test/TestVersion.aspx");
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3 * 1000);

            String text = doc.body().text();

            System.out.println(text); // outputs 1
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return title;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //if you had a ui element, you could display the title
        //((TextView)findViewById (R.id.myTextView)).setText (result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your URL says webpage not available. Check it

Comment: Hi, this is just a dummy value I posted because it is not possible to publish the real page. I am pretty sure I can see the page via browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem. We should pass the real IP instead of private IP for the url.